# Создать свой Slider WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Так как стандартные контролы мне не подходят, я решил написать некоторые самостоятельно. Но вот когда я дошел до Slider то попал в тупик. Не понимаю как мне создать его с помощью UserControl. Есть у кого-то информация на эту тему или кто умеет и может разобратся? Я не понимаю как сделать передвигающийся  Thumb с привязкой и указывать интервалы. Хочется полностью свой элемент создать

Comment: Слайдер - понятие растяжимое, что только слайдерами не называют. Что конкретно вы имеете в виду? Покажите вашу попытку его реализовать - разметку и код юзерконтрола, ну и как выглядит.

Comment: Вы должны использовать не usercontrol, а custom control, для этого они и предназначены

Comment: Или возможно вам нужно просто написать стиль, и переопределить template?